Embedding the space to be attached into the adjunction
(Note that I am NOT asking about the space onto which glueing is done.)
I am skeptical of the following statement:

Let $A\subseteq X$ and $f\colon A\to Y$ be continuous and injective. Then $X$ embeds inside $X\cup_f Y$ via the quotient map $q$.

Suppose it is true. For simplicity (and w.l.o.g.), let $X\cap Y = \emptyset$. Now, for any open $U$ in $X$, we must have that $q(U) = q(X)\cap \mathcal U$ for some open $\mathcal U$ in $X\cup_f Y$. But then, this means that $\mathcal U = q(U\cup K)$ for some $K\subseteq Y\setminus f(A)$ (due to injectivity; details in the footnote1). This is open precisely when (due to injectivity) $U\cup f(U\cap A)\cup K$ is open in $X\cup Y$, which is open iff $f(U\cap A)\cup K$ is open in $Y$.
Thus, the statement is equivalent to finding a $K_U$ for any $U$ such that $f(U\cap A)\cup K_U$ is open. But, is this really ensured by mere injectivity of $f$? I believe that something more is needed (an easy sufficient condition being openness of $f$). What do you think?

1 To see this, take $q^{-1}$ on both the sides of $q(U) = q(X)\cap \mathcal U$, yielding (due to injectivity) $U\cup f(U\cap A) = (X\cup f(A))\cap q^{-1}(\mathcal U)$ so that we get $U = X\cap q^{-1}(\mathcal U)$ and $f(U\cap A) = f(A)\cap q^{-1}(\mathcal U)$, i.e., $Y\cap q^{-1}(\mathcal U) = f(U\cap A)\cup K$ for some $K\subseteq Y\setminus f(A)$. Thus, $q^{-1}(\mathcal U) = U\cup f(U\cap A)\cup K$ so that $\mathcal U = q(U\cup f(U\cup A)\cup K)$, which equals $q(U\cup K)$.

Indeed, one can give a counterexample:
If $f\colon A\to Y$ is a surjective non-open, then there exists an open $U\subseteq X$ such that $f(U\cap A)$ is not open. (Note that $K$ must be empty for $f$ is surjective.)
